# Does it need to release a IBOutlet control? (non ARC )

Tags: ios

I saw others code and property of controls had non property, retain option and synthesize.

When do they (controls) are alloc in lifecycle of viewcontrol?
I wonder if they need release.

Following controls (UIView, UIButton, UILabel) need release?

```
@interface TreatDuplicationHold : UIViewController <TransactionManagerDelegate, NWPickerFieldDelegate, SearchCompDelegate, SearchCardReaderDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *_mainTableView;

    IBOutlet UIView *_headerHoldView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_tranHoldDateView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_searchHoldView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_detailHoldView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_resultHoldView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_dateSelectView;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *_datePicker;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_btnAddData;

    IBOutlet UILabel *_lblSelectAll;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_lblSelectScreen;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_btnSelectAll;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_btnSelectScreen;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_btnRequestHoldFree;

    IBOutlet NWPickerField *_bpCompPicker;
}
```

Here is implement.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_arrHidData release];

    [TRANS release];
    [_arrItemList release];
    [_arrHidData release];
    [_arrCheckBoxValue release];

    [_startDate release];
    [_endDate release];

    // Here release IBOutlet control. 
    [_tranHoldDateView release];
    [_searchHoldView release];
    [_detailHoldView release];
    [_resultHoldView release];
    [_headerHoldView release];
    [_mainTableView release];
    [_dateSelectView release];
    [_datePicker release];
    [_bpCompPicker release];
    [_btnAddData release];
    [_btn_CallAgency release];
    [_btn_CallBCCard release];

    [_imvSelectAll release];
    [_imvSelectScreen release];
    [_lblSelectAll release];
    [_lblSelectScreen release];
    [_btnSelectAll release];
    [_btnSelectScreen release];
    [_btnRequestHoldFree release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Cocoa memory management rules apply.

- Any instance of a class that wishes to take ownership of an instance should call retain.
- To avoid a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), ownership should be taken unless it will result in a [retain cycle](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html). In the case of a retain cycle, the instance designated as the 'owner' should nil out any references on non-owners during deallocation.

In the case of interface builder, dependencies are injected into your controller/view using the information in a meta-data file (XML generated by Interface Builder). `[instance release]` should be called if your properties are using the 'strong' scope. (And based on the above two points, they should be).

In your code above you've used ivars instead of properties. I'm not sure if this will work correctly under manual memory management. However it will certainly be correct if you use properties instead of ivars. Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *headerHoldView;
```

. . if you do this, the auto-synthesized setter will take ownership when that setter is called. (It will also release ownership of a non-nil previous value). Therefore this will ensure:

- There's no dangling pointer as long as the class is being used.
- Memory will be correctly freed when the class is deallocated.

Its pretty amazing that ARC can give 90% of the benefits of a garbage collector (the only difference being special treatment for retain cycles), but it all happens at compile-time, which is efficient because there's there's no extra CPU clicks or battery drain that would apply if there *was* a garbage collector. Unless you're studying memory management (which is a good thing) its recommended to use ARC. In ARC its possible to mostly forget about reference counting and just focus on breaking any retain cycles. The rest is handled by the compiler.

Comment: Have been using ARC for so long, that it wasn't easy to write this answer.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, My partner has not learned the use of ARC yet. :D